# Facebook marketing API without payment

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to create facebook marketing API referring this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis). I have created Campaign->Advert Set->Advert. But in last it is asking for Place Order. I am in development phase only. How to create test campaigns without any payment?

Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Facebook has now available a sandbox ad accounts.

> Sandbox mode is a testing environment that helps developers to create an ad account that is enabled for read and write Marketing API calls. However it doesn't actually deliver ads.

https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2016/10/19/sandbox-ad-accounts/